# Rails, external url redirection issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

when I use `redirect_to` this way:

`redirect_to "https://google.com`

There is no problem.
But when I get the url from a method:

```
redirect_to external_url
```

.
.
.

```
def external_url
  "https://google.com"
end
```

I am getting this Error :

```
 ERROR URI::InvalidURIError: URI must be ascii only "http://localhost:3000\u{202b}\u{202a}https://google.com"
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have some extra unicode characters somewhere in that string. I would try re-typing the method and url from scratch, without copying and pasting.